# IQueryable IGrouping how to work

Tags: .net, list, generics, iqueryable, igrouping

i return such type `IQueryable< IGrouping<int, Invoice>> List()`
how can i work with it? like with generic `List<Invoice>` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, you have a `IGrouping<int, Invoice>` as your list member.

Each grouping has a `Key` property allowing you access to the key of the group and an `IEnumerable<Invoice>` containing the grouped Invoices.

So to access it ...

```
IQueryable< IGrouping<int, Invoice>> List() groupedIvoices = //... get your grouping
foreach (var group in groupedIvoices ) {
    var key = group.Key;
    var invoicesInGroup = group.ToList();
}
```

Look at [101 Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) for samples and explanations for the different Linq functions.

Comment: @user276640: Was writing it while you commented :-)